# java Double division versus BigDecimal round half_up half_down

Tags: java

I know this topic is quite covered. But when I read the answers to BigDecimal topics, I got confused.
I hope you are not to mad I am starting this topic.

I am creating a program to do a very simple division with couple of numbers. I have two variables that represent sums of money. The precision of variables and answer is 5 digits after zero (x.xxxxx). I want my answer to be as precise as possible (still 5 digits after zero, but precise rounding).

So there is my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a =1.0;
        double b =3.0;
        double c;
        c=(double)Math.round((a/b)*100000)/100000;
        System.out.println(c); //prints 0.33333

        BigDecimal d= new BigDecimal("1.0");
        BigDecimal e = new BigDecimal("3.0");
        BigDecimal f;
        f=d.divide(e, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        System.out.println(f);//prints 0.33333

        BigDecimal k = new BigDecimal(1.0);
        BigDecimal l = new BigDecimal(3.0);
        BigDecimal m;
        m=k.divide(l, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        System.out.println(m);//prints 0.33333

        BigDecimal o= new BigDecimal("1.0");
        BigDecimal p = new BigDecimal("3.0");
        BigDecimal q;
        q=o.divide(p, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println(q);//prints 0.33333

    }
```

Question 1: Why does RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN give same answer as RoundingMode.HALF_UP. Shouldn't one of them give 0.33334.
Question 2: In which case is there a difference in presion, when I compare dividing two doubles and rounding them by force to using BigDecimal HALF_DOWN.
Question 3: Shouldn't there be a difference when I use bigdecimal constructor with string versus with double. In which case there is difference?
Question 4: Which method do you suggest when calculating money, why?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you divide 1.0 by 3.0 the result is 0.333333333...  If you read the spec you will see that ROUND_HALF_UP and ROUND_HALF_DOWN only produce different results if the discarded fraction is exactly 0.5, otherwise they behave the same.  So you're seeing what one would expect.

If you are performing a calculation on money that has any real significance (producing financial reports, calculating sales tax, etc) then you need to understand what rounding mode is legally expected in your situation.  Don't be a cowboy.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING` and `BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR`

```
f=d.divide(e, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
m=k.divide(l, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
q=o.divide(p, 5, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING);
```

instead of `RoundingMode.HALF_UP` and `RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN`

```
f=d.divide(e, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
m=k.divide(l, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
q=o.divide(p, 5, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

output

```
0.33333
0.33333
0.33334
```